# delete everythin in the string after a certain character

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to delete everything after and including 'rr' in a string for example

12345rr234 should be 12345

I've tried (rcs) is the variable i'm using

```
  rtrim(rcs,'rr')
```

but i get the error

```
The rtrim function requires 1 argument(s).
```

Comment: Do any rows have an `rcs` that doesn't contain `rr`?

Comment: rtrim is used to 'r'ight 'trim' spaces from the end of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SUBSTRING(rcs,1,CHARINDEX('rr',rcs)-1)
```

Will do, provided that `rcs` always actually contains an `rr` sequence.

Comment: they should always contain a rr but they may be the first 2  characters

Comment: @user1296762 - and should it just be an empty string in that case?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Didn't your first solution return an empty string when `'rr'` are the first chars anyway? (no need for the `CASE`)

Comment: @Lamak - I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Checks if rr is present, if not it returns the complete value:

```
DECLARE @rcs varchar(50)
SET @rcs='12345rr234'
SELECT 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('rr',@rcs) > 0 THEN
    LEFT(@rcs,CHARINDEX('rr',@rcs)-1) ELSE
    @rcs
END
```